# Pig sum on data

Tags: sum, apache-pig

I have a file like - 
(1950,10)
(1951,33)
(1952,15)
(1953,17)
(1954,17)
(1955,14)
(1956,60)
(1957,98)
(1958,73)
(1959,87)
(1960,123)

I want to get the sum of the second field through Pig.
eg out put should be like 
(547)

Please help

Comment: Please show what you have done so far and where did you get stuck, this will make it more likely to get responses from the community. And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Basically I have very large data, and after the below steps I boiled down to the data I have given, on which I need the total count.                    movies = load '/sat_exer/Pig/movies' USING PigStorage(',') as (ID:int, name:chararray, year:int, rating:float, duration:int);
movies_a = filter movies by (year >=1950 and year <=1960);
A1 = group movies_a by year;
A2 = foreach A1 Generate group as year, COUNT(movies_a) as kount;
A3 = group A2 by year;
A4 = FOREACH A3 GENERATE group, SUM(A2.count) as Total:int ;

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question too include this code. The text editor there has told for formatting code that would make this much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.   You have to group all your records..

```
 x = LOAD '/root/stack.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (year:int,score:int);
 y = GROUP x ALL;
 z = FOREACH y GENERATE SUM(x.score);
 dump z;
```

Answer:

```
(547)
```

Is that solves your problem......

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my problem is i have the intermediate relation, is there any way I can get my desired result with out storing the file and using that?

Comment: Can you please write the code what you have trying to do